# Navigating to a <div data-role="page"> without using anchor tag

Tags: jquery, html, window.location

I have two div tags in single HTML with data-role as 'page'. First one is a form which contains a table with two columns say A and B and a button.The second page contains a text box and dropdown and sublit button. On clicking of button in first page jquery should call web-service and should navigate to second div in which, the dropdown should be filled with result of webservice.
Finally on clicking submit whole data should be converted to a xml and should be posted to another webservice.

Please help me in this scenario

HTML PAGE

```
     <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page-a">
        <div data-role="header"><h1>Place order</h1></div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <table align="center">
            <tr>
            <th>Part Number</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="t1"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="q1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="t2"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="q2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="t3"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="q3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="t4"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="q4"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="t5"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="q5"></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
    </div>
    <center>
    <div>
        <a href="#page-b" id="nextpage" data-role="button">Next</a></center>
        <!--<button  onclick="jaffa()">NEXT  </button>-->
    </div>
    </center>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="page-b">
        <div data-role="header"><h1>Head</h1></div>
        <div data-role="content">
        <table align="center">
        <tr>
        <td> <label for="uname" class="floatleft" >Customer Reference ID</label>     </td>
        <td> <input id="cref"type="text" name="name" size="20"  data-mini="true"  autocomplete="off" style="width:220px;" class="floatleft1"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><label for="address" class="floatleft">Address</label></td>
        <td><select id="addr">
        <option>--SELECT--</option>
        </select></td>
        </tr>
       </table>             
        </div>
        <div>
      <button  onclick="execute()"> place order </button>
      </div>

    </div>
```

SCRIPT

```
      <script type="text/javascript"> 
       $.("#nextpage").click(function)()        {
    alert("jaffa");
    $.ajax({

            type: "POST",

            url:"http://172.18.98.31/TrwAftermarket_M/login.asmx/GetShipToList",
            data: {UserId:"TRW2008" , Storefront:"DE" , CustomerNumber:"987654"},
            dataType: 'xml',
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){

            var xml = '';
            xml = $(data).find('string').text();
            xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
            $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
            $(xml).find('shiptoName').each(function(){
                                    var value = $(this).text();
                                    //alert(value);

                                    $(addr).append("<option class='ddlcustomer' value='"+ value +"'>"+value+"</option>");
                                });
        },

         error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                                      alert("Error occured");
                                        alert(textStatus); 
                                       alert(errorThrown);
                         } 

                    });
               });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var position = $('#page-a').position();

$("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: position.top
});
```